# Enemy chase AI and animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So im making a 2d RPG on unity , and im having trouble im the enemy AI. When i did the player movement script, his animations change as the input_x and input_y change, so its easy to control, but the enemy wont have any input, so how can i manage his animation to be facing the right way as he chases the player or flees.

This is my player mov script >

```
  public class PlayerMovment : MonoBehaviour {
  Animator anim;
  Rigidbody2D playerRgdb;

  void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    playerRgdb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  }


  void Update () {
  Vector2 movement_vector = new      Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));   
  if (movement_vector != Vector2.zero)
  {
    anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
    anim.SetFloat("input_x", movement_vector.x);
    anim.SetFloat("input_y", movement_vector.y);

  }
  else
  {
    anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
  }
  playerRgdb.MovePosition(playerRgdb.position + movement_vector *               Time.deltaTime);
   }
   }
```

Comment: Even though your enemies aren't actually taking input from a controller, it's a good idea to program them as if they are getting input from somewhere. That would mean you could reuse player code in the enemies to control the things they have in common, like animations.

Comment: where in your code do you set the direction the characters are looking to?

Comment: @Aleksandrus the Animator has 3 parameters, input_x,input_y and isWalking, When isWalking is true, he goes to the  Walking state, wich plays 4 animations : Walk_Up (if X = 0, y = 1), Walk_Down (if X=0,Y=-1), Walk_RIght (if x=1 , y=0) , Walk_Left (if x=-1, y=0)